# C# dependency Injection <interface> is a type which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, moq, repository-pattern

I am trying to learn a bit about dependency injection within C#, so i can mock up tests. I am trying to use a respository pattern, and here the EnviromentRepository as a service. However, its not going to plan. I am getting the compiler error CS0119.

My main reasoning for learning this is to understand a code set from work a little better. Which is a bit more complex than my 4 provided code snippets.

"IEnviromentRepository is a type which is not valid in the given context."

I could do with a set of eyes to correct where i have gone wrong, or point me at something im missing.

Thanks in advance.

The .cs where i am getting the issue, where i call .getService

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WarpStorm.Objects.Enviroment
{
    public class EnviromentsSetup
    {
        private readonly IEnviromentRepository _enviromentRepository;
        
        public EnviromentsSetup() : this(Startup.BuildContainer())
        {
        }

        public EnviromentsSetup(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (serviceProvider == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
            }

            _enviromentRepository = serviceProvider.GetService<IEnviromentRepository> ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_enviromentRepository));
        }
    }
}
```

I include supprting classes/Interfaces below

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using WarpStorm.Objects.Enviroment;

namespace WarpStorm.Objects
{
    public static class Startup
    {
        public static IServiceProvider BuildContainer()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            ConfigureServices(services);

            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        private static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IEnviromentRepository, EnviromentRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace WarpStorm.Objects.Enviroment
{
    public interface IEnviromentRepository
    {
        Enviroment GetByName(string name);
    }
}
```

```
namespace WarpStorm.Objects.Enviroment
{
    public class EnviromentRepository : IEnviromentRepository
    {
        private readonly IList<Enviroment> _enviroments;

        public EnviromentRepository(IList<Enviroment> enviroments)
        {
            _enviroments = enviroments;
        }

        public virtual Enviroment GetByName(string name)
        {
            return _enviroments.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
        }
    }
}
```

I dont expect the IEnviromentRepository to be classed as a type, as its an interface. Well, its also a type as its in  after the GetService. But i would expect it not to give me the CS0119 compiler error. I have looked at examples from my work, but those examples are not quite the same, as they are for an DynamoDb AWS/Lambda solution. Not a solution for me farting about with a simple, local repository.

Comment: Just a typo: `GetService<IEnviromentRepository>()`, add the braces

Answer (score 0):

Is this a typo on the namespace?  You are missing the "n" in Environment.

UPDATE: Sorry, I didn't see that you answered your own question before posting my answer.